# Executing javascript function upon returning result in MVC controller action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm stuck with the following scenario: There is a list of items on a page. Each item has a `href` that redirects it to the needed controller and action, i.e. when the list is populated each item's href is set to `/Controller/Action/Parameter`. Consequently, this is not a AJAX post, it's just a redirect when clicking on an item in the list (so no `onSuccess` unfortunately).

The respective controller action then retrieves a response from the repository. Now I need to display the response results in a dialog that pops up over the current page.

I currently implemented a solution with javascript: `function ShowDialog(data)`. This displays the dialog and binds the data.

I have been trying without success to find a way to return a JavaScript result in my controller action that will call `ShowDialog`. Is this the way to go? Can I call javascript functions like that, returning `JavaScript(someScript)`?

Answer (score 3):

You might have better luck making a [jQuery AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Bind a `click` event to the link, like this:

```
$(a.myLink).click(function(){
   $.ajax($(this).attr('href'), {
      success: function(data){
         showDialog(data);
      },
      'datatype': 'html'
   })
});
```

This requires your link to have a class `myLink`, but you can select the link(s) in any way you wish.